# Determine sample size so that it guarantees that the length of the confidence interval is less than $\frac{\sigma}{4}$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Suposing $\sigma^2$ unkown, find the minimum value for n that gurantees with a probability of 90% that the 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ is of a length no more than $\frac{\sigma}{4}$

Ive been trying to figure this one out using the method to find confidence intervals for sample means, but i get stuck on how to implement the 90% probability

i used that when $\sigma^2$ is uknown the confidence interval is given by:
$P(\overline{X}-t^{1-\alpha/2}_{n-1}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}<\mu<\overline{X}+t^{1-\alpha/2}_{n-1}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}})=1-\alpha$

and from there i get that the inequality for the length of the interval will be given by:

$2t^{0.975}_{n-1}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{\sigma}{4}$        (using $\alpha =.05$)

but i dont know how to proceed from here because i need to achieve:
$P(2t^{0.975}_{n-1}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{\sigma}{4})=.9$

Comment: It might be a good idea to show us exactly what you have tried, even if you know it's wrong. Or perhapse even just write what the method to find confidence intervals for sample means is, just so we can understand a little better how you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @C-RAM thank you for the suggestion, already added more info

Comment: You state explicitly that the variance is unknown, and implicitly from the effort to find a confidence interval for the mean $\mu$, we must assume that is unknown.  Are we to assume a normal distribution for the population?  Or is the Question motivated by interest in non-parametric ([distribution free](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/statistics-definitions/parametric-and-non-parametric-data/)) tests?

Comment: $S^2$ has a distribution. You can use that to find the $.9$ quantile of it, solve for $n$. However, since this depends on $n$, it makes things a bit messier, but with some clever programming you can probably solve it

Comment: @AndresArriaga Why don't you apply the central limit theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: According to CLT for sample variance, if the 4th central moment of iid function exists, then sample variance converges in distribution to a normal distribution. By applying Delta method, we can get sample standard deviation in distribution to a normal distribution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of $t^{0.975}_{n-1}$ suggests you may be assuming the data is taken from a normal distribution of unknown mean and variance, or at least that a normal approximation for the distribution of the sample mean will be good enough without worrying too much about the distribution of the sample variance - this latter point may be over-optimistic in some cases.

As a back of an envelope calculation, if that number was approximately $2$  then your confidence interval would have length of about $\frac{4S}{\sqrt{n}}$ and you would want $\frac{4S}{\sqrt{n}} \approx \frac\sigma4$, i.e. $n \approx \left(16 \frac{S}{\sigma}\right)^2$, so something perhaps of the order of magnitude of $16^2=256$.  That is going to be too low, because $S$ could be larger than $\sigma$ and we want to meet the $90\%$ issue.  We can also improve on the $t_{n-1}$ calculation.

Meanwhile $(n-1)\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ and we want to be looking at $\mathbb P\left(\frac{2 t^{0.975}_{n-1} S}{\sqrt{n}}\le \frac \sigma4\right) \ge 0.90$ i.e. finding the smallest $n$ with $$\mathbb P\left((n-1)\frac{ S^2}{\sigma^2}\le \frac {n(n-1)}{(8 t^{0.975}_{n-1})^2}\right) \ge 0.90.$$

So let's ask R:

```
n <- 1:1000
min(which(pchisq(n * (n-1) / (8 * qt(0.975, df=n-1))^2, df=n-1) >= 0.9))
# 276
```

giving $n= 276$.

As expected, the back of an envelope estimate was too low but a reasonable order of magnitude.  Looking around these two values, we can see the probabilities of the confidence interval width being less than $\frac\sigma 4$:

```
n <- 256:280
cbind(n, prob=pchisq(n * (n-1) / (8 * qt(0.975, n-1))^2, n-1))

    n      prob
# 256 0.6482046
# 257 0.6649897
# 258 0.6814720
# 259 0.6976226
# 260 0.7134144
# 261 0.7288224
# 262 0.7438238
# 263 0.7583979
# 264 0.7725262
# 265 0.7861928
# 266 0.7993840
# 267 0.8120886
# 268 0.8242978
# 269 0.8360052
# 270 0.8472067
# 271 0.8579005
# 272 0.8680870
# 273 0.8777688
# 274 0.8869503
# 275 0.8956380
# 276 0.9038399
# 277 0.9115659
# 278 0.9188272
# 279 0.9256362
# 280 0.9320067
```